# How to check if an array of dates has the value of an array of objects specific value inside and push to a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Im looking to take an array of dates(from range selection) and then run through each date and check if that date exists in and list of objets.

If the date value is not in the list of objects then I would like to push the value of 0 to a new array if the value does exits in the array of objects I would like to take push objects "amount" from the specific object where the date is to the new array. Please see example below

```js
const newArray = []

const dateArray1 = ['2022-02-03','2022-02-04','2022-02-05','2022-02-06','2022-02-07','2022-02-08']

const objArray2 = {"orders":[
 
  {
    "id": 4419830775973,
    "sale_amount" :200,
    'date':'2022-02-03'
  },
  
   {
    "id": 44198340775973,
    "sale_amount" :100,
    'date':"2022-02-05"
  },
  
   {
    "id": 4419660775973,
    "sale_amount" :700,
    'date':'2022-02-08'
  },
  
],}
```

New pushed array would be - `newArray[200, 0, 100, 0, 0, 700]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a map keyed by date from your object array, and then map the dates to amounts using that map:

```js
const dates = ['2022-02-03','2022-02-04','2022-02-05','2022-02-06','2022-02-07','2022-02-08']

const sales = { "orders": [
    { "id": 4419830775973,  "sale_amount" :200, 'date':'2022-02-03' },
    { "id": 44198340775973, "sale_amount" :100, 'date':"2022-02-05" },
    { "id": 4419660775973,  "sale_amount" :700, 'date':'2022-02-08' }
]};

const map = new Map(sales.orders.map(o  => [o.date, o.sale_amount]));
const result = dates.map(date => map.get(date) ?? 0);
console.log(result);
```